# Angular Material md-menu-content height issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

In Angular Material you can set the width the of md-menu-content section within an md-menu by setting the width eg.

```
<md-menu-content width="2">
```

Is there a way to do the same for height? Using height="x" doesn't seem to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I just used this css: `md-menu-content { max-height: 90vh; }`, which allows the menu height to grow up to 90% of the view height.  Works great!